# How to allow users to launch EC2 instances only from Service Catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've created a Service Catalog portfolio and product intending to allow users to launch their own quality assurance environments. I have given a selection of users the AWS Managed Policy "ServiceCatalogEndUserFullAccess" (below) so they can launch products, however they seem to also require individual permissions for the resources created by the template (in this case, just an EC2 and ELB).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "catalog-user:*",
            "cloudformation:CreateStack",
            "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
            "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "cloudformation:GetTemplateSummary",
            "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
            "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate",
            "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "servicecatalog:DescribeProduct",
            "servicecatalog:DescribeProductView",
            "servicecatalog:DescribeProvisioningParameters",
            "servicecatalog:ListLaunchPaths",
            "servicecatalog:ProvisionProduct",
            "servicecatalog:SearchProducts",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "servicecatalog:DescribeRecord",
            "servicecatalog:ListRecordHistory",
            "servicecatalog:ScanProvisionedProducts",
            "servicecatalog:TerminateProvisionedProduct",
            "servicecatalog:UpdateProvisionedProduct"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "servicecatalog:userLevel": "self"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

As such, the template fails in CloudFormation and rolls back with an error like the following:

```
API:ec2:runInstances - You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Ideally I'd like to restrict the user's ability to launch an EC2 either from Service Catalog only, or perhaps more specifically our staging VPC, but neither seems possible from what I've read currently. Is there any way to grant this level of granular permission such that the user can only launch the resources in the particular Service Catalog product they've chosen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your policy has granted users permission to *use* Service Catalog, but that is not sufficient to permit them to launch the actual resources.

There are two ways to **grant permission to launch resources** (eg Amazon EC2):

- Grant permissions to the **IAM Users** themselves, or
- Assign a **Launch Role** to the Launch Constraint for the product

From [Applying a Launch Constraint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/latest/adminguide/constraints-launch.html) documentation:

> Without a launch constraint, end users must launch and manage products with their own IAM credentials. To do so, they must have permissions for AWS CloudFormation, the AWS services used by the products, and AWS Service Catalog. By using a **launch role**, you can instead limit the end users' permissions to the minimum that they require.

Therefore, **create a Launch Role with the necessary permissions to Launch an EC2 instance** but only grant the users the minimum necessary permissions to launch the product from Service Catalog.

Comment: Excellent answer. I eventually stumbled upon this, but it was not as apparent in the docs as I would have liked. You made it clear - products can be launched either with the permissions of the IAM user who provisions them, or you can assign IAM roles as launch constraints to grant extra-ordinary privileges to the user. For anyone else who finds this, I will add that I made use of the STS AWS CLI call 'decode-authorization-message' on the rest of my initial error to determine that the actual error was that I needed to have the IAM:passRole permission to give an IAM role to my instance.